# How to combine multiple queries into one and fetch data using single while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, pdo

I have this code how can I combine multiple queries and their result into one ?

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
include('pdoConfig.php');
$response = array();
$sql1     = $dbh->prepare("select * from orders_assigned where delivery_status != 'Cancelled' && order_status='Picked'");
$sql1->execute();
$count1 = $sql1->rowCount();
if ($count1 >= 1) {
    while ($row1 = $sql1->fetch()) {
        $delivery_status = $row1['delivery_status'];
        $deliveryboy_id  = $row1['username'];
        $order_id        = $row1['order_id'];
        $sql2            = $dbh->prepare("select * from delboy_login where id = ?");
        $sql2->bindParam(1, $deliveryboy_id);
        $sql2->execute();
        $row2      = $sql2->fetch();
        $del_name  = $row2['name'];//name
        $del_lat   = $row2['lat'];//lat
        $del_longi = $row2['longi'];//long
        $del_icon  = $row2['icon'];//icon
        $sql3      = $dbh->prepare("select * from `order` where `order_id` = ?");
        $sql3->bindParam(1, $order_id);
        $sql3->execute();
        $row3       = $sql3->fetch();
        $address_id = $row3['address_id'];
        $user_id    = $row3['user_id'];
        $sql4       = $dbh->prepare("select * from customer_login where cust_id = ?");
        $sql4->bindParam(1, $user_id);
        $sql4->execute();
        $row4 = $sql4->fetch();
        $cus_name  = $row4['name'];//name
        $sql5 = $dbh->prepare("select * from address where a_id = ?");
        $sql5->bindParam(1, $address_id);
        $sql5->execute();
        $row5      = $sql5->fetch();
        $cus_lat   = $row5['lat'];//lat
        $cus_longi = $row5['longi'];//long
        $cus_icon  = $row5['icon'];//icon

        $tmp            = array();
        $tmp['lat']     = $del_lat;//i want use $cus_lat here too
        $tmp['content'] = $del_name;//i want use $cus_name here too
        $tmp['lng']     = $del_longi;//i want use $cus_longi here too
        $tmp['icon']    = $del_icon;//i want use $cus_icon here too
        array_push($response, $tmp);
    }
}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Using this I can only get either $del_ data or $cus_ data I want use both. I have multiple tables for same data but I can not combine tables because both are different kind of users. As I am not good at joins so I don't know how to use joins here.

By using one of query provided below i am getting this

```
{
"delivery_status" : Delivered,
"username" : 1,
"order_id" : 5,
"del_name" : Boy One,
"del_lat" : 26.8808383,
"del_longi" : 75.7503407,
"address_id" : 31,
"user_id" : 1,
"cus_name" : Roylee Wheels,
"cus_lat" : 20.593684,
"cus_longi" : 78.96288
},
{
"delivery_status" : Processing,
"username" : 1,
"order_id" : 6,
"del_name" : Boy One,
"del_lat" : 26.8808383,
"del_longi" : 75.7503407,
"address_id" : 30,
"user_id" : 1,
"cus_name" : Roylee Wheels,
"cus_lat" : 20.594725,
"cus_longi" : 78.963407
},
```

and so on...

I want final output like this

```
{
"icon" : "icon path here",
"del_name" : "Boy One",
"del_lat" : 26.8808383,
"del_longi" : 75.7503407,
},
{
"icon" : "icon path here",
"cus_name" : "Roylee Wheels",
"cus_lat" : 20.594725,
"cus_longi" : 78.963407
},
```

and so on...

Comment: _"As I am not good at joins"_ Isn't this the perfect opportunity to get better at it? What better incentive is there than this?

Comment: What i use for training my SQL skill is using HeidiSQL software (which is free). In this software you can login on your database and manage it. Additionally you can make queries in which you train your skills. (However this is personal)

Comment: i want final output like this

Answer (score 0):

```
select orders_assigned.*, order.*, address.* 
from orders_assigned
inner join delboy_login on delboy_login.id = orders_assigned.delboy_login
inner join `order` on `order`.`id` = orders_assigned.order_id
inner join customer_login on customer_login.cust_id = order.user_id
inner join address on address.a_id = order.address_id
where delivery_status != 'Cancelled' && order_status='Picked'
```

You need to join your tables. this is untested, so something like this.

It's bad practice to select * from tables, you should really be defining only the fields you need.

Also note that order is a reserved word in mysql so not a good name for a table - hence the backticks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    orders_assigned.delivery_status AS delivery_status,
    orders_assigned.username AS username,
    orders_assigned.order_id AS order_id,
    delboy_login.name AS del_name,
    delboy_login.lat AS del_lat,
    delboy_login.longi AS del_longi,
    order.address_id AS address_id,
    order.user_id AS user_id,
    customer_login.name AS cus_name,
    address.lat AS cus_lat,
    address.longi AS cus_longi
FROM
    orders_assigned
        LEFT JOIN
    delboy_login ON delboy_login.id = orders_assigned.username
        LEFT JOIN
    orders ON order.order_id = orders_assigned.order_id
        LEFT JOIN
    customer_login ON customer_login.cust_id = order.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    address ON address.a_id = order.address_id
```

Here is the SQL you want.

Take note that you can rename the columns that the query returns as you can see from below.

```
    delboy_login.name AS del_name,
    delboy_login.lat AS del_lat,
    delboy_login.longi AS del_longi,

    customer_login.name AS cus_name,
    address.lat AS cus_lat,
    address.longi AS cus_longi
```

Joining table is very important, I hope that you will be able to pick up the query pattern in the future.

Best of luck to you.

EDIT:

The output you desire can be achieved by simply creating 2 different temp_arrays, and pushing them into the main array one after the other.

```
if ($count1 >= 1) {
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        $delivery_status = $row['delivery_status'];
        $deliveryboy_id  = $row['username'];
        $order_id        = $row['order_id'];
        $del_name  = $row['del_name'];//name
        $del_lat   = $row['del_lat'];//lat
        $del_longi = $row['del_longi'];//long
        $del_icon  = $row['del_icon'];//icon
        $address_id = $row['address_id'];
        $user_id    = $row['user_id'];
        $cus_name  = $row['cus_name'];//name
        $cus_lat   = $row['cus_lat'];//lat
        $cus_longi = $row['cus_longi'];//long
        $cus_icon  = $row['cus_icon'];//icon

        $tmp_del                 = array();
        $tmp_del['del_lat']      = $del_lat;
        $tmp_del['del_name']     = $del_name;
        $tmp_del['del_longi']    = $del_longi;
        $tmp_del['del_icon'] = $del_icon;

        $tmp_cus               = array();
        $tmp_cus['cus_lat']    = $cus_lat;
        $tmp_cus['cus_name']   = $cus_name;
        $tmp_cus['cus_longi']  = $cus_longi;
        $tmp_cus['cus_icon']   = $cus_icon;

        array_push($response, $tmp_del);
        array_push($response, $tmp_cus);
    }
```

Comment: this works at some what but in your query all results combine in one but i want like del_name and cus_name fetch as name like so others, what i am using this code for is i am placing markers on google map using this data so i want individual cus_name and del_name as separate marker with its lat long in single query

Comment: i am getting this:-  "delivery_status" : Delivered,
"username" : 1,
"order_id" : 5,
"del_name" : Boy One,
"del_lat" : 26.8808383,
"del_longi" : 75.7503407,
"address_id" : 31,
"user_id" : 1,
"cus_name" : Roylee Wheels,
"cus_lat" : 20.593684,
"cus_longi" : 78.96288   i want 
{"del_name" : Boy One,
"del_lat" : 26.8808383,
"del_longi" : 75.7503407,
},{
"cus_name" : Roylee Wheels,
"cus_lat" : 20.593684,
"cus_longi" : 78.96288}

Comment: @AnilBairwa just updated the answer. See if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It will work !

```
SELECT oa.delivery_status, oa.username oa.order_id, dl.name, dl.lat, dl.longi, o.address_id, o,user_id, cl.name, a.lat, a.longi
FROM orders_assigned as oa 
JOIN delboy_login as dl ON oa.username = dl.id 
JOIN order as o ON oa.order_id = o.order_id
JOIN customer_login as cl ON  = o.user_id = cl.cust_id
JOIN address as a ON  = o.address_id = a.a_id
WHERE oa.delivery_status != 'Cancelled' && oa.order_status='Picked'
```